# Why is mmap not working here

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, x86-64, mmap

I get segmentation fault when I run the following piece of code...

```
int * x = mmap( 0, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, 0, 0 );

x[0] = 42; // <--- Segmentation fault happens due to this
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Have you checked if the call to mmap was successful?

Comment: File descriptor 0 (the last-but-one argument) is a character device. Maybe you want -1?

Answer (score 9):

You've specified the incorrect flags and file descriptor.  It looks like what you want is an anonymous (not backed by a file) mapping.  If that's the case, the correct call would be:

```
x = mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

You need to use the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag to tell Linux there is no file.  And you should pass `-1` for the file descriptor, not 0.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got it. I forgot to place **MAP_ANONYMOUS**, so it should had been like this...

```
int * x = mmap( 0, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, 
  0, 0 );
```

Its working this way.

Comment: Specify fd as -1. In linux fd is ignored when MAP_ANONYMOUS is specified. but some unix implementation requires it. Portable applications should pass fd as -1.

Answer (score 1):

`man mmap` says:

`On success, mmap() returns a pointer to the mapped area. On error, the value MAP_FAILED (that is, (void *) -1) is returned, and errno is set appropriately`

Check, whether `x == MAP_FAILED` or not. May be this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

And you should always check that the result of `mmap` is not `MAP_FAILED` (that is, `(void *) -1`) and use `errno` to get the error code in that case.

Your `mmap` could fail (e.g. because of resource limits set with [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit), or because the swap space is full).